# does jquery or google app engine have ability to disable queries that originate from external domain

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a web app in Google App Engine for Java. I plan to store and retrieve some JSON data using Jquery.

What I want to know is, can I create a setting in my web app/in app engine, so that any json fetches that originate from external domains, are automatically rejected/not responded to?

So that only my web app's json fetch requests work correctly?

I am not sure if this requires some settings changed in jquery or app engine or both...

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing of the question is ambiguous. I'm assuming you meant "The client I'll be serving from App Engine will make JSON requests back to the server. How do I ensure that the server only responds to JSON requests from the client code that I've served?"

Are you requiring that users of your app be logged in? If so, make the handler that serves JSON also require login. That's an easy way to protected yourself. If you're not concerned about logged-in users make fake requests, you're done.

Does this help?

Comment: thanks thats what i meant (that the server only responds to JSON requests from the client code)...

Comment: is there some way to prevent logged in users from making erroneous or fake requests? That would be ideal for me...maybe some way, in which the response to a request will be computed only if the request is from a specific url?? thanks anyway, your response was most helpful...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent a user from simply composing a request that's byte-for-byte identical to one a browser would send, and sending it themselves - the only data your app has to go on is that which the user sent you voluntarily.

The best you could do is embed a token in the page you return and require that same token to be present in all requests - but this won't prevent an adversary from simply fetching your page to get a valid token, and using it until it expires.